# Updating part of a JS Object that is defined as a variable referencing location in larger object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

When using large nested JavaScript objects referencing deep values becomes very tedious. Is there a way to reference object's sub-location (to update data) with a simple variable to make the code cleaner?

```
const data = {
 a: {
  x: {
   0: [],
   1: [],
  },
  y: {
   0: [],
   1: [],
  },
 b: {
  ...
 }
}
```

So if I want to add a value to a.x.0 array I could do something like this (which as far as I can tell does not update the original object array, only ax variable):

```
let ax = data['a']['x'];
ax['0'].push(value);
```

Instead of:

```
data['a']['x']['0'].push(value);
```

Comment: `ax` is not a copy, it is a reference, so yes it will update original

Comment: *which as far as I can tell does not update the original object array, only ax variable* - that's not the case, what makes you think that?

Comment: Remember you can just write data.a.x[0]  you don't need all those [''] in there. Also, since there isn't an inbuilt way to target a deep path, why not write your own? It's fairly simple to create a function called getValueAtPath() which takes a string like 'a.x.0' and the advantage is that your get function can handle checking for nulls so you never have to worry . Or you can use a library someone else wrote....Google should show a bunch - here's one http://ignitersworld.com/lab/jsonQ.html

Comment: See here, just to be sure: https://jsfiddle.net/tevemadar/8p2gthny/

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I've realized that the program misbehaved due to some spaghetti variable assignments (so I guess I misdiagnosed the problem).